# Search by an inputstream property

Tags: full-text-search, inputstream, jackrabbit, jcr

I have a question about making a xpath expression for filtering resources by a property of type `inputStream` called data.
How can I do a text search, for example this is working:

```
String xpath1 = "<my app path>//element(*, nt:resource) [jcr:contains(@jcr:mimeType,'*plain*')]";
String xpath2 = "<my app path>//element(*, nt:resource) [jcr:contains(@jcr:encoding,'*utf*')]";
```

But this is not working.

```
String xpath3 = "<my app path>//element(*, nt:resource) [jcr:contains(@jcr:data,'*plain*')]";
```

The really fact is that we use some custom nodes, let's explain the properties definitions:

**In Java Terms...**

```
public class Resource extends BaseNode {

  /** Encoding media type. It cannot be null or empty. */
  @Field(jcrName = "jcr:encoding", jcrDefaultValue = "")
  private String encoding;

  /** Resource's MIME type. It cannot be null or empty. */
  @Field(jcrName="jcr:mimeType", jcrDefaultValue = "")
  private String mimeType;

  /** Resource's size (bytes). */
  @Field(jcrName="skl:size")
  private long size;

  /** Resource's content data as stream. It cannot be null. */
  @Field(jcrName="jcr:data")
  private InputStream data;

  ...
}

@Node(jcrType = "baseNode", isAbstract = true)
public abstract class BaseNode {

  @Field(jcrName = "name", id = true)
  protected String name;

  @Field(jcrName = "creationDate")
  protected Date creationDate;

  ...
}
```

**And in JackRabbit Terms...**

```
<!-- Base node type definition -->
  <nodeType name="docs:baseNode"
            isMixin="false"
            hasOrderableChildNodes="false" >
    <supertypes>
      <supertype>nt:hierarchyNode</supertype>
    </supertypes>
    <propertyDefinition name="docs:name"
                        requiredType="String"
                        autoCreated="false"
                        mandatory="true"
                        onParentVersion="COPY"
                        protected="false"
                        multiple="false" />
    <propertyDefinition name="docs:searchPath"
                        requiredType="String"
                        autoCreated="false"
                        mandatory="false"
                        onParentVersion="COPY"
                        protected="false"
                        multiple="false" />
    <propertyDefinition name="docs:creationDate"
                        requiredType="Date"
                        autoCreated="false"
                        mandatory="true"
                        onParentVersion="COPY"
                        protected="false"
                        multiple="false" />
    <propertyDefinition name="docs:lastModified"
                        requiredType="Date"
                        autoCreated="false"
                        mandatory="true"
                        onParentVersion="COPY"
                        protected="false"
                        multiple="false" />
    <childNodeDefinition name="*"
                         defaultPrimaryType="docs:baseNode"
                         autoCreated="false"
                         mandatory="false"
                         onParentVersion="COPY"
                         protected="false"
                         sameNameSiblings="false">
      <requiredPrimaryTypes>
        <requiredPrimaryType>docs:baseNode</requiredPrimaryType>
      </requiredPrimaryTypes>
    </childNodeDefinition>
  </nodeType>


  <!-- Resource node type definition -->
  <nodeType name="skl:resource"
            isMixin="false"
            hasOrderableChildNodes="false" >
    <supertypes>
      <supertype>docs:baseNode</supertype>
      <supertype>nt:resource</supertype>
    </supertypes>
    <propertyDefinition name="skl:size"
                        requiredType="Long"
                        autoCreated="false"
                        mandatory="true"
                        onParentVersion="COPY"
                        protected="false"
                        multiple="false" />
    <propertyDefinition name="skl:externalUri"
                        requiredType="String"
                        autoCreated="false"
                        mandatory="false"
                        onParentVersion="COPY"
                        protected="false"
                        multiple="false" />
  </nodeType>
```

The point is, how do I do this query in order to filter by the jcr:data property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to turn on text extraction so that the searchable text from your "jcr:data" property will be indexed. See [this email thread](http://jackrabbit.510166.n4.nabble.com/jcr-sql2-contains-full-text-search-not-working-tt4655655.html#a4655938) on the Jackrabbit discussion list.

BTW, the JCR [CND format](http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/2.0/25_Appendix.html#25.2.3%20CND%20Grammar) is a much more compact way of describing your node types.

Comment: Thanks for the data Randall. I will check it out!. Infortunately where are using a older version of Jackrabbit that doesn't follow 2.0 JCR spec (yes.. we are out of dated, and afraid of moving all to another version.. it's just to huge, the story of software itself you know what we are talking about ejjeje).

Comment: I understand. Note that the JCR 2.0 API is backward compatible with JCR 1.0 - all JCR 1.0 code should be supported (assuming the implementation did their job correctly). Yes, a few methods are deprecated (often because they're far from ideal; e.g., `Node.save()`), but they still should work. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks you very much for your support and your encouragement! Sadly, i still cannot figure out how to solve these problem... but i will have in mind your advice.